# Windows 8 IndexedDB createObjectStore

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, windows-runtime

Trying to build a Metro app using Javascript and having issues with IndexedDb. I cannot create an object store. My code is shown below. I'm doing this on success of the open() function.

```
dbReq.onsuccess = function (evt) {
  var txn = evt.target.transaction;
  var db = evt.target.result;
  if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains("test")) {
    var store = db.createObjectStore("test");
  }
}
```

Every time, it throws an exception on the 'createObjectStore' call that says

> 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [object IDBDatabaseException]

[Over here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/a63ce772-0d88-4e90-a4b5-84fce275987f) they talk about it and it's a nice example to look at too, but still, did not help me.
Notice that control hits the one line of code inside 'if' statement. So 'db' is not null and is valid. But I saw that the transaction is null - not sure if that is an issue or even if you are supposed to get a valid transaction back at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why it was not working. Switched to using roaming settings and it is very easy to use.

```
roamingSettings.values[SETTING_NAME] = SETTING_VALUE;
```

To read, of course,

```
var temp = roamingSettings.values[SETTING_NAME];
```